# Openpyxl writing rows results a TypeError

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to write Rows from sheet1 to sheet2 if column D has value greater than 5. But I am facing an error. Below is the code and the error:

```
import openpyxl

Runwb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\Python\\ExtractReport\\Top5.xlsx')

""" Create new sheet Top5 """
Runwb.create_sheet(title="Top5")
Runwb.save("C:\\Python\\ExtractReport\\Top5.xlsx")
print("Top5 sheet Created")

""" Create new instance to copy """
"""Runwb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\Python\\ExtractReport\\Top5.xlsx')"""
Rawsheet = Runwb['Raw']
Top5sheet = Runwb['Top5']
TestDetailwb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\Python\\ExtractReport\\TestDetails.xlsx')

Testdetailsheet = TestDetailwb['TestDetails']

""" Copy Data to Results """""
for row in range(Rawsheet.max_row):
      for col in range(Rawsheet.max_column):
          if (Rawsheet.cell(row+1, column=4).value) > Testdetailsheet.cell(row=2, column=2).value:
                Top5sheet.cell(row+1, col+1).value=Rawsheet.cell(row+1, col+1).value
print("Top5 sheet Updated")
Runwb.save("c:\\Python\\ExtractReport\\Top5.xlsx")
```

result is

```
========================== RESTART: C:\Python\Top5.py ==========================
Top5 sheet Created
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Top5.py", line 20, in <module>
    if (Rawsheet.cell(row+1, column=4).value) > Testdetailsheet.cell(row=2, column=2).value:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare a string with an integer amount-wise which results a TypeError:

`TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

To compare the values you should cast the read value (`(Rawsheet.cell(row+1, column=4).value)`) into a numeric type with something like `int(Rawsheet.cell(row+1, column=4).value)` but that will only work when the value is a number as string (like `"6"`).

So you should first:

- check if the value is a number as string
- convert the value to int/float
- check which is greater

In practice:

If you have a function like this:

```py
def is_cell_greater(value_as_string_a, value_as_string_b):

    if type(value_as_string_a) is str and value_as_string_a.isnumeric():
        value_as_string_a = int(value_as_string_a)

    if type(value_as_string_b) is str and value_as_string_b.isnumeric():
        value_as_string_b = int(value_as_string_b)

    if type(value_as_string_b) is int and type(value_as_string_a) is int:
        return value_as_string_a > value_as_string_b
    else:
        # do something, return False or raise exception
        pass
```

You can do:

```
if is_cell_greater(Rawsheet.cell(row+1, column=4).value, Testdetailsheet.cell(row=2, column=2).value):
   Top5sheet.cell(row+1, col+1).value=Rawsheet.cell(row+1, col+1).value
```

Comment: I tried using i=2  int(Rawsheet.cell(i, column=4).value)  it works but if I increment values i+=1 it gives below error      TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: The reason why `if type(value_as_string_a) is str` is in the answer is to prevent that error. `None` can't be casted (converted) to `int`.